# Replacing a standard UITableViewCell with a custom cell on selection

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` with standard `UITableViewCells`. On selecting a cell, I would like to replace that cell with a custom cell with `UITextViews` instead of the `detailTextLabel` and `UITextFields` instead of the accessoryView. What would be the best way to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Add in your `UITextField` or `UITextField` (whichever is appropriate for your solution) to the `contentView`, and make them hidden. Override the `-setSelected:animated:' method:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
  if ( animated ) {
    // using old-school UIView animation support to fade in/out controls,
    // block-based much easier, but only 4.0 or greater
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    self.textLabel.alpha = (selected) ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    self.detailTextLabel.alpha = (selected) ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    // assumed you added a UITextView 'textView' ivar
    self.textView.alpha = (selected) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
  else {
    self.textLabel.hidden = selected;
    self.detailTextLabel.hidden = selected;
    self.textView.hidden = !selected;
  }
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context
{
  self.textLabel.hidden = self.selected;
  self.detailTextLabel.hidden = self.selected;
  self.textView.hidden = !self.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a normal cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. On `didSelectrowAtIndexPath:`, do a tableview reload.

Keep track of row selections using a global flag and every time before constructing a cell, check the flag and decide what type of cell to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it simpler to always use your custom table view cell, but have a different appearance when it is selected (for example when setSelected is called you can alter your subviews or colors or whatever).